# Getting user profile property with dash in name with rest api

Tags: rest, user-profile

I have a custom user profile property named "My-Property".

I want to retrieve this property from a rest call.

How can I handle the dash in the property name ?

I tried :

- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=My-Property`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/My-Property`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=My%20Property`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/My%20Property`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=MyProperty`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/MyProperty`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=MyProperty`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=UserProfileProperties/My-Property&$expand=UserProfileProperties/My-Property`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=UserProfileProperties/My%2DProperty&$expand=UserProfileProperties/My%2DProperty`
- `http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/?$select=UserProfileProperties/MyProperty&$expand=UserProfileProperties/MyProperty`

With no luck.

What is the correct way to get this property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you will need to use **"GetUserProfilePropertyFor"** function.Please try below URL.

http://server/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='SPS-Birthday')?@v='Enter Current User Account Detail'

Reference Link : http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter/select on custom user property. It is a known issue. So its doesnt matter whether there is dash in the property or not.

User voice link - [Enable selecting custom User Profile Properties from REST API](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147027-enable-selecting-custom-user-profile-properties-fr)

So you can use them as below:

For On Prem -

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='My-Property')?@v='domain\username'
```

For Online -

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='My-Property')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com'
```

Full code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://sitecollectionurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='SPS-JobTitle')?@v=%27i:0%23.f|membership|user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com%27",
      type: "GET",
      headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data){        
      }
});
```

Reference - [SharePoint 2013: Get UserProfile Properties with REST API](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, according [Sam's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/207423/3497), here is my full code to retrieve the profile property for the logged user :

```
// 1st request to get the user login
jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getmyproperties/accountname",
    headers :{Accept :"application/json;odata=verbose"},
    dataFilter: function (data, type) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data).d.AccountName;
        return JSON.stringify(result);
    }                
}).done(function(accountname) { 

    // 2nd request to get the property value
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountname=@v,propertyName='My-Property')?@v='"+accountname+"'",
        headers :{Accept :"application/json;odata=verbose"},
        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data).d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;
            return JSON.stringify(result);
        }
    }).done(function(myProperty){
        // final code when got the property
        console.log(myProperty);
    });

});
```